# Wireshark - Don't mask non-printable characters (Windows)

Tags: windows, wireshark, character-encoding

Is there any way to have Wireshark running under Windows not mask non-printable characters in the packet view on the bottom? Currently, any characters `< 0x20` and `>= 0x7f` are shown as `.`  This behavior makes it very hard for me to make sense of a packet's content dump, as I typically use a font with OEM/DOS encoding which has a unique glyph for each ASCII character `0` to `0xff`, and lets me makes sense of a binary dump much easier than looking at hex codes.

Example view in Wireshark:
[image]

Desired view of packet dump (exact same font, with no non-printable char substitution):
[image]

Comment: Those 00 padding are useful in many cases. For easy detection, single click on the second row (for example the source port 57695) and WireShark will highlight it in those hex bytes (01 BB).

Comment: This is fairly esoteric - you are likely to get more traction in [Wireshark's forum](https://ask.wireshark.org) where many of the developers participate in answering questions.